# Change Default X11 Forwarding Port

Tags: ssh, x11

I want to run X11Forwarding support through my sshd, but the machine has direct Internet access. I would like to change the default port of 6010 to some other port number at the least, but ideally I would also like to have it only listen for localhost connections.

Comment: It is listening on localhost only by default.

Comment: Why can I see it from another machine with: nmap -Pn -p 6010 <IP_ADDR>

Comment: Because you've set other than default options or something else is listening not sshd.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: It is Debian Jessie Lite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

X11 should be configured to only allow local access, and with xauth, so only the correct user can connect.

Then `ssh` can be used to connect to a remote machine, with `ssh -X`.

Comment: If it is only allowing local access, then why can I see the port listening from another machine?

Comment: Yes, set your firewall to block it. And look at the X11 configuration.